# AngularJS Codeigniter http url last segment

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, url

My url is this http://localhost/fcm/Maps/create_deped_cm/1/1/1. When I use my https in angular the response would be a php page because the post url will be http://localhost/fcm/Maps/create_deped_cm/1/1/do_add_deped_cm. When I test and find the answer the post url should be http://localhost/fcm/Maps/do_add_deped_cm. How can I achieve this?

angularjs code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('config', [])
.constant('appName','My Angular App!')
.constant('appVersion','0.3')
.constant('baseUrl','http://localhost/fcm/');

var app = angular.module("myCurriform_deped", ['config']);



   app.controller("standardCtrl", function($scope,$http,$filter,$location,$window,config) {
   .......................

   });
```

Comment: replace url with `/fcm/Maps/do_add_deped_cm` -  should work

Comment: @ajaiJothi still not working. I tried then the outcome would be http://localhost/fcm/Maps/create_deped_cm/1/1/fcm/Maps/do_add_deped_cm

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined a base url in your app's config file:

```
angular.module('myApp.config', [])
    .constant('appName','My Angular App!')
    .constant('appVersion','0.3')
    .constant('baseUrl','http://localhost/fcm/');
```

Make sure your config is included in your module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.config']);
```

Then just append your url to the base and use that:

```
var url = config.baseUrl + 'Maps/do_add_cm_deped'
```

That should do the trick.

---

*app.js*

```
angular
.module('config', []).constant('baseUrl','http://localhost/fcm/');

angular
.module('myCurriform_deped', ['config'])
.controller("standardCtrl", function($scope,$http,$filter,$location,$window,config) {
         $scope.submit_button = function(params) {
             // submit logic
             var url = config.baseUrl + 'Maps/do_add_cm_deped';
             var req = {
                 url: url,
                 // other properties
             }
         }
    });
```

Comment: is this line inside my controller? var url = config.baseUrl + 'Maps/do_add_cm_deped'. I get an error that says config is not defined.

Comment: @TepTep have you created the myApp.config module?

Comment: in the same file as your app module.. and inject it into your app's list of dependencies..

Comment: yes, but the url variable needs to be declared in the `submit_form` function and then used in the `req` variable like this - `var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: { 
                ...
               }
           }`

Comment: I got a console error saying config is not defined.

Comment: still not working. look at my new edit codes here. I got error Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider  help me please